# Coq leb <=? does not give me an hypothesis after case or induction

Tags: coq

I have simplified my situation to the following piece of code, hopefully this makes it easier to understand.

I would like to prove the following Lemma:

```
Require Import Arith.
Lemma example: forall a b, 
  if a<=?b then a<=b else a > b.
```

Doing the following step in the proof

```
Proof.
intros.
```

Gives me the result

```
1 subgoal
a, b : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
if a <=? b then a <= b else a > b
```

It seems trivial that either `a` is smaller than or equal to `b`, in which case I could prove `a<=b`. In the other case that `b` is larger than `a` I could prove that `a>b`.

I've tried to prove this with `induction(a<=?b)` or `case (a<=?b)` but both give me the following result.

```
2 subgoals
a, b : nat
______________________________________(1/2)
a <= b
______________________________________(2/2)
a > b
```

Now I have no way to prove these goals. I expected to gain an hypothesis such as `H: a <= b` and `H: a > b` in the second case. This way, I would be able to prove my goals.

Could anybody tell me how I could this issue of the non-appearing hypothesis?

Edit:
The whole lemma can be proven as follows:

```
Require Import Arith.
Lemma example: forall a b, 
  if a<=?b then a<=b else a > b.
Proof.
intros.
Check Nat.leb_spec.
case (Nat.leb_spec a b);intuition.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the case distinction that you are looking for you can use

```
Nat.leb_spec : forall x y : nat, BoolSpec (x <= y) (y < x) (x <=? y)
```

The type `BoolSpec` embodies exactly what you are trying to do: if `(x <=? y)` is *the boolean* `true`, then *the proposition* `x <= y` is true, and if `(x <=? y` is `false` then `y < x` is true. Thus, `Nat.leb_spec` embodies the specification of the function `x <=? y`, as its name suggests.

Now using `case (Nat.leb_spec a b)` does exactly what you were trying to do with `case (a <=? b)`: it gives you two subgoals, one where `x <=? y` is replaced by `true` and you have `x <= y` as an extra hypothesis, and the other where `x <=? y` is replaced by `false` and you have `y < x` as an hypothesis instead. The fact that you case distinction was on a term of type `BoolSpec` rather than simply `bool` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I now managed to prove the whole lemma. I will put the whole proof in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `<=?` is function returning a boolean, either `true` or `false`. When you ask Coq to do an induction or a case analysis on the expression `a <=? b`, it does exactly that and reduces the proof to two cases: one where `a <=? b` is substituted by `true` and another where it is substituted by `false`. If you want to keep track of the destructed value, you should ask explicitly for it using `destruct (a <=? b) eqn:H.` (see the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=induction#coq:tacv.destruct-%E2%80%A6-eqn:)).

Comment: I see! So I tried this but then my hypothesis becomes `H : (a <=? b) = true`. Although I'm happy I now have something to work with, I really don't know how to proceed from that hypothesis to `a <= b`. Would you have any suggestion on that? If not, that's ok as well the other answer suggesting `Nat.leb_spec` solved it for me.

Comment: One way or another you need to relate `a <=? b = true` with `a <= b` and it is not totally trivial. `Nat.leb_spec` is one good way to do so.